# What happened to the carcass of Smaug after the events of The Hobbit?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-hobbit, smaug

What happened to the carcass of Smaug after the events of The Hobbit?

I remember reading that Smaug fell into the flaming ruins of Laketown (and that many tried to dive in later for the riches it may have carried?) - but what then? Was the carcass left there to rot? Could visitors see its bare, huge bones stick out of the water?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

According to the description of the events given on page 254 in chapter 14, *Fire and Ice* , Smaug's bones remained where they had fallen. As far as I can recall, their status wasn't mentioned again in the post-Hobbit *Lord Of The Rings* novels.

> They removed northward higher up the shore; for ever after they had a
> dread of the water where the dragon lay. He would never again return
> to his golden bed, but was stretched cold as stone, twisted upon the
> floor of the shallows. There for ages his huge bones could be seen in
> calm weather amid the ruined piles of the old town. But few dared to
> dive into the shivering water or recover the precious stones that fell
> from his rotting carcase.
>
> *The Hobbit*- p.254